# Why JTable column not change?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I can get data from the database and store it in a `JTable`. All works well but if I edit the data from the table and press enter data does not edit.

Value is not overridden in the table after being changed.

**Constructor and getter/setter**

```
public class employee {
    private Integer emp_code;
    private String f_name;
    private String l_name;
    private Integer age;
    private String birth;
    private String nationality;
    private String gender;
    private String contact;
    private String contact2;
    private String address;
    private Integer gov_id;
    private String passport_no;
    private String profile;

    public employee(Integer emp_code, String f_name, String l_name, Integer age, String birth, String nationality, String gender, String contact, String contact2, String address, Integer gov_id, String passport_no, String profile) {
        this.emp_code = emp_code;
        this.f_name = f_name;
        this.l_name = l_name;
        this.age = age;
        this.birth = birth;
        this.nationality = nationality;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.contact = contact;
        this.contact2 = contact2;
        this.address = address;
        this.gov_id = gov_id;
        this.passport_no = passport_no;
        this.profile = profile;
    }

    // getter setter

}
```

**TheModel**

```
public class TheModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private String[] columns;
    private Object[][] rows;
    private boolean[] edit;

    public TheModel() {
    }

    public TheModel(Object[][] data, String[] columnName, boolean[] canEdit) {
        this.rows = data;
        this.columns = columnName;
        this.edit = canEdit;
    }

    public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
        if (column == 12) {
            return Icon.class;
        } else {
            return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
        }
    }

    public int getRowCount() {
        return this.rows.length;
    }

    public int getColumnCount() {
        return this.columns.length;

    }

    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return this.rows[rowIndex][columnIndex];
    }

    public String getColumnName(int col) {
        return this.columns[col];
    }

    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return edit[columnIndex];
    }

}
```

**Java SWING File**

```
private void btnSearchActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        getEmployee();
      } 

public void getEmployee() {

        ArrayList<employee> list = getTable();
        String[] columnName = {"Code", "f_name", "l_name", "Age", "Birth", "Nationality", "Gender", "Contact", "Contact2", "Address", "Gov. id", "Passport no", "Profile"};
        boolean[] canEdit = new boolean[]{
            false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false
        };
        Object[][] rows = new Object[list.size()][13];
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            rows[i][0] = list.get(i).getEmp_code();
            rows[i][1] = list.get(i).getF_name();
            rows[i][2] = list.get(i).getL_name();
            rows[i][3] = list.get(i).getAge();
            rows[i][4] = list.get(i).getBirth();
            rows[i][5] = list.get(i).getNationality();
            rows[i][6] = list.get(i).getGender();
            rows[i][7] = list.get(i).getContact();
            rows[i][8] = list.get(i).getContact2();
            rows[i][9] = list.get(i).getAddress();
            rows[i][10] = list.get(i).getGov_id();
            rows[i][11] = list.get(i).getPassport_no();
            if (list.get(i).getProfile() != "") {
                ImageIcon MyImage = new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon(list.get(i).getProfile()).getImage()
                        .getScaledInstance(70, 50, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));

                rows[i][12] = MyImage;
            } else {
                rows[i][12] = null;
            }

        }

        TheModel model = new TheModel(rows, columnName, canEdit);
        model.fireTableDataChanged();
        jTable1.setModel(model);
        jTable1.setRowHeight(50);
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(12).setPreferredWidth(70);
    }

    public ArrayList<employee> getTable() {
        ArrayList<employee> list = new ArrayList<employee>();
        PreparedStatement pst;
        ResultSet r;
        try {
            Connection cn = null;
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            cn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/car_inventory_system", "root", "");
            pst = cn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM employee_registration_master WHERE f_name = ? OR l_name = ?");
            pst.setString(1, txtSearch.getText());
            pst.setString(2, txtSearch.getText());
            r = pst.executeQuery();
            employee e;
            while (r.next()) {
                e = new employee(
                        r.getInt("emp_code"),
                        r.getString("f_name"),
                        r.getString("l_name"),
                        r.getInt("age"),
                        r.getString("birth"),
                        r.getString("nationality"),
                        r.getString("gender"),
                        r.getString("contact"),
                        r.getString("contact2"),
                        r.getString("address"),
                        r.getInt("gov_id"),
                        r.getString("passport_no"),
                        r.getString("profile")
                );
                list.add(e);
            }
            pst.close();
            cn.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return list;
    }
```

This is before Edit value. here down `l_name` is `Dourcy` and i change it to `Leach`:

[image]

This is after Edit value. here down `l_name` is not change it to `Leach`:

[image]

Comment: My immediate thought is, you didn't implement [`TableModel#setValueAt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html#setValueAt(java.lang.Object,int,int))

Comment: But I directly push data through `ArrayList<>`

Comment: The cell editor will notify the table the cell editing has stopped.  The table will take the value from the editor and pass that value to the `TableModel` via the `setValueAt` method.  You're then expected to update the underlying data

Comment: I would recommend reading the section on [Editors and Renders](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) from [How to Use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I change it to `setValueAt` but error is `void type allowed here` see above my question...

Comment: Right, so what did you understand from the compilation error message, as well as looking at the Java docs for both method calls? Note that reading the documentation is something we need to do a lot of as programmers. Please don't consider SO to be the 'first stop' when you see one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put, you need to override `setValueAt` of the `TableModel`.  When a cell "stops" editing, it notifies the `JTable`, the `JTable` takes the cell value and calls the `TableModel`'s `setValueAt` method.  You're then expected to update the model, as per the models requirements and generate a suitable modified event.

For example...

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();

                List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>(25);
                employees.add(new Employee(1, "Jack", "Dourcy", 28, "03-11-2000", "American", "Male", "No of your business", "Stop spamming me", "Some place, some where", 45, "123456789", "Smiley"));

                JTable table = new JTable();
                TheModel model = new TheModel(employees);

                table.setModel(model);

                frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class Employee {

        private Integer emp_code;
        private String f_name;
        private String l_name;
        private Integer age;
        private String birth;
        private String nationality;
        private String gender;
        private String contact;
        private String contact2;
        private String address;
        private Integer gov_id;
        private String passport_no;
        private String profile;

        public Employee(Integer emp_code, String f_name, String l_name, Integer age, String birth, String nationality, String gender, String contact, String contact2, String address, Integer gov_id, String passport_no, String profile) {
            this.emp_code = emp_code;
            this.f_name = f_name;
            this.l_name = l_name;
            this.age = age;
            this.birth = birth;
            this.nationality = nationality;
            this.gender = gender;
            this.contact = contact;
            this.contact2 = contact2;
            this.address = address;
            this.gov_id = gov_id;
            this.passport_no = passport_no;
            this.profile = profile;
        }

        public Integer getEmp_code() {
            return emp_code;
        }

        public void setEmp_code(Integer emp_code) {
            this.emp_code = emp_code;
        }

        public String getF_name() {
            return f_name;
        }

        public void setF_name(String f_name) {
            this.f_name = f_name;
        }

        public String getL_name() {
            return l_name;
        }

        public void setL_name(String l_name) {
            this.l_name = l_name;
        }

        public Integer getAge() {
            return age;
        }

        public void setAge(Integer age) {
            this.age = age;
        }

        public String getBirth() {
            return birth;
        }

        public void setBirth(String birth) {
            this.birth = birth;
        }

        public String getNationality() {
            return nationality;
        }

        public void setNationality(String nationality) {
            this.nationality = nationality;
        }

        public String getGender() {
            return gender;
        }

        public void setGender(String gender) {
            this.gender = gender;
        }

        public String getContact() {
            return contact;
        }

        public void setContact(String contact) {
            this.contact = contact;
        }

        public String getContact2() {
            return contact2;
        }

        public void setContact2(String contact2) {
            this.contact2 = contact2;
        }

        public String getAddress() {
            return address;
        }

        public void setAddress(String address) {
            this.address = address;
        }

        public Integer getGov_id() {
            return gov_id;
        }

        public void setGov_id(Integer gov_id) {
            this.gov_id = gov_id;
        }

        public String getPassport_no() {
            return passport_no;
        }

        public void setPassport_no(String passport_no) {
            this.passport_no = passport_no;
        }

        public String getProfile() {
            return profile;
        }

        public void setProfile(String profile) {
            this.profile = profile;
        }

    }

    public class TheModel extends AbstractTableModel {

        private List<Employee> employees;

        private String[] columns = new String[] {
            "Code", "First name", "Last name", "Age", "Birth date", "Nationality",
            "Gender", "Contact", "Contact", "Address", "Gov. Id", "Pass", "Profile"
        };

        public TheModel(List<Employee> employees) {
            this.employees = employees;
        }

        public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
            switch (column) {
                case 0:
                case 3:
                case 10: return Integer.class;
                default: return String.class;
            }
        }

        public int getRowCount() {
            return employees.size();
        }

        public int getColumnCount() {
            return columns.length;

        }

        public String getColumnName(int col) {
            return this.columns[col];
        }

        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            Employee employee = employees.get(rowIndex);
            switch (columnIndex) {
                case 0: return employee.getEmp_code();
                case 1: return employee.getF_name();
                case 2: return employee.getL_name();
                case 3: return employee.getAge();
                case 4: return employee.getBirth();
                case 5: return employee.getNationality();
                case 6: return employee.getGender();
                case 7: return employee.getContact();
                case 8: return employee.getContact2();
                case 9: return employee.getAddress();
                case 10: return employee.getGov_id();
                case 11: return employee.getPassport_no();
                case 12: return employee.getProfile();
            }
            return null;
        }

        public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            switch (columnIndex) {
                case 1:
                case 2: return true;
                default: return false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            Employee employee = employees.get(rowIndex);
            switch (columnIndex) {
                case 1:
                    if (aValue instanceof String) {
                        String newValue = (String)aValue;
                        employee.setF_name(newValue);
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    if (aValue instanceof String) {
                        String newValue = (String)aValue;
                        employee.setL_name(newValue);
                    }
                    break;
            }

            fireTableCellUpdated(rowIndex, columnIndex);
        }

    }
}
```

Please note, I've updated the model to take direct advantage of your `Employee` POJO, rather the mucking about with arrays and stuff.

I would recommend reading the section on [Editors and Renders](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) from [How to Use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

Comment: thank you so much it's worked and i  find the way to set `Profile` to `imageIcon`

Comment: If edit `F_name` and `L_name` all column changed to the value of this both column

Comment: @FaeemazazBhanej Fixed (mixing logic from different languages)